# Connect to MySQL from VBA without a driver

Tags: mysql

I installed xampp on my computer and I want another computer to access the mysql db in vba. But, they don't have admin right on their computer and cant get it, and they dont have mysql ado driver installed.

Is there a way to do it without this driver - can I use a portable driver or a windows standard lib?

At the moment all I can do is create a php page and use post data with a sql query, getting the result as xml or whatever, which is really not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the correct ODBC driver the app won't be connecting to the database directly.  You'll have to do through some sort of middle tier that does have the driver installed.

Your solution here is to have the user call the help desk and have them install the MySQL drivers on his PC.  If this is business critical it shouldn't be hard to get it approved.  If not you'll need to redesign the app to fit within the IT policies.